# Kotlin: How can I cancel an ongoing timer with the press of any three buttons, and then restarts the timer?

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, reset

Kotlin: How can I cancel an ongoing timer with the press of any three buttons, and then restarts the timer?

I would be extremely grateful if someone can give me some insight.
Thank you in advance!

**Background:**
I am trying to create a rock-paper-scissors game that has an instruction (win!, lose!, get a draw!)

There are two timers in the game, a main game timer, and a question timer. You have 4 seconds to choose the correct answer hand based on the shown hand and the instruction.

Every time the question timer gets to 0:

1. The timer will reset itself
2. Gets a "wrong" evaluation and adds question total
3. Randomize the question (hand) and instruction (win! lose! get a draw!)

If you answer before the timer runs out by clicking on choiceRock, choicePaper, choiceScissors:

1. The timer will reset and countdown again
2. Randomize the question (hand) and instruction (win! lose! get a draw!)
3. Evaluate answer (if correct, gets 0 / 0 C => 1 / 0 C; if wrong, 0 / 0 C => 0 / 1 C)

I already have the randomize functions for hand and instruction outside of the timer.
I also already have the evaluate function outside of the timer.
And the timer works, and restarts when it reaches 0.

But I need the timer to restart normally when either choiceRock, choicePaper, choiceScissors buttons is pressed.

========================================================================

It would be extremely helpful as well if anyone can tell me:

1. how to call the randomize functions inside the timer without having to re-write the function inside the timer onFinish. (if you click on the start button that only appears on the beginning of the game, it will call the randomize function which is outside of the timer)
2. How to make the onFinish happen after 1, not after 0.

I coudlnt find much info on Kotlin timer stuff... It has been really frustrating, and I want to move on to new projects for practice.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

**Code for the question timer:**

```
fun startQuestionTimer() {
        object : CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                binding.questionTimer.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
                binding.evaluationResult.setImageResource(R.drawable.evaluation_wrong)
                totalQuestions ++
                binding.correctAnswersCounter.text = "$correctAnswers / $totalQuestions C"

                this.start()

                fun generateQuestionImage() {
                    questionImageId = Question().generateQuestionImageId()

                    when (questionImageId) {
                        1 -> binding.questionHand.setImageResource(R.drawable.question_rock)
                        2 -> binding.questionHand.setImageResource(R.drawable.question_paper)
                        else -> binding.questionHand.setImageResource(R.drawable.question_scissors)
                    }
                }

                fun generateQuestionInstruction() {
                    questionInstructionId = Question().generateQuestionImageId()

                    when (questionInstructionId) {
                        1 -> binding.questionInstruction.text = "WIN!"
                        2 -> binding.questionInstruction.text = "LOSE!"
                        else -> binding.questionInstruction.text = "GET A DRAW!"
                    }
                }

                generateQuestionImage()
                generateQuestionInstruction()
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

**Code for the choiceRock button:**

```
binding.startButton.setOnClickListener {
        binding.startButton.isVisible = false
        binding.questionTimer.isVisible = true
        startTimer()
        startQuestionTimer()
        generateQuestionImage()
        generateQuestionInstruction()
    }
```

**Things I have tried:**

1. Inserting the choiceRock, choicePaper and choiceScissors onclicklisteners inside the timer, but somehow the timer acts weirdly.
2. Used this.cancel() inside the timer, but the timer just glitches.
3. I tried cancelling inside the choiceRock etc onclicklisteners, but apparently it doesnt work since i cant call a method on a function (startQuestionTimer().cancel())
4. A bunch of other stuffs take took hours but either froze the timer or make the timer acts up

Comment: Your countdown timer is local, you should pull it outside the function, then you'd be able to cancel it from anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can assign the timer to a variable so that you can access it afterwards.

```
        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTick")
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFinish")
            }
        }.start()
```

For the above code i have assigned counter to a timer variable which can be reused later like

```
timer.cancel()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works! I didn’t know you could assign the timer to a variable. Thank you so much!